# How do I import matplotlib in python2.7 using conda

Tags: python-2.7, conda, spyder

I have installed matplotlib like Conda install matplotlib from my Conda env(lumia) and when I check it shows

```sh
(lumia) [~]$ conda list | grep matplotlib
matplotlib                2.2.3            py27hb69df0a_0
```

but when I run the python script, its showing ImportError: No module named matplotlib. My version is python 2.7. I tried all suggestion in this site and the error still persists

Comment: (*Spyder maintainer here*) Please read [our guide](https://github.com/spyder-ide/spyder/wiki/Working-with-packages-and-environments-in-Spyder) to understand how to solve this problem.

Comment: Sorry, I was running scripts in spyder through a different environment. When I changed, there is a different error ImportError: No module named axes_grid1. And I am not able to solve this

Comment: That looks like an installation issue with Matplotlib. You could try to run `conda install -f matplotlib` to see if that fixes it.

Comment: I solved it. I needed to update the path in spyder (Tools-python preferences)

Comment: Great! Glad you were able to solve this by yourself.